# why can we use a NSManagedObjectContext without setting its persistentStoreCoordinator in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

the normal initialize of a context is like this:

```
lazy var context : NSManagedObjectContext = {
let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
return context
}()
```

but why i can initialized the context in this way:

```
var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?
lazy var note: Note? = {
if let context = self.managedObjectContext {
  return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? Note
}
return .None
}()
```

if i don't set the persistentStoreCoordinator,which way will the context store the entity.by the way,this is not the first context created in the demo,it is just the context for a manageredobject named Node

waiting online ..........

the whole code is :

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class CreateNoteViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
 var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?
  lazy var note: Note? = {
   if let context = self.managedObjectContext {
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? Note
}
return .None
}()

  @IBOutlet var titleField : UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var bodyField : UITextView!
  @IBOutlet var attachPhotoButton : UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var attachedPhoto : UIImageView!

   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
if let image = note?.image {
  attachedPhoto.image = image
  view.endEditing(true)
} else {
  titleField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
 }


   @IBAction func saveNote() {
  note?.title = titleField.text
  note?.body = bodyField.text

  if let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext {
  do {
  try  managedObjectContext.save()
}
  catch let error as NSError {
print("Error saving \(error)", terminator: "")
  }
  }
  performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToNotesList", sender: self)
 }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    saveNote()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "AttachPhoto" {
if let nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? AttachPhotoViewController {
nextViewController.note = note
}
    }
  }
   }
```

the function of the viewcontroller is to pick a photo from the local alarm,and save the title, the Node is used to save all the information,so the author did use the default context(even i don't know why he don't use the default context),he initialize a new context to save the node ,even not set anything ,its amazing ,even the path of file path he haven't set,
 i will show you the default of stack:

```
     import Foundation
      import CoreData

     class CoreDataStack: CustomStringConvertible {
       var modelName : String
       var storeName : String
       var options : [String : AnyObject]?

        init(modelName:String, storeName:String, options: [String : AnyObject]? = nil) {
self.modelName = modelName
self.storeName = storeName
self.options = options
      }

         var description : String {
return "context: \(context)\n" +
  "modelName: \(modelName)" +
  "storeURL: \(storeURL)\n"
       }

  var modelURL : NSURL {
return NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.modelName, withExtension: "momd")!
   }

    var storeURL : NSURL {
var storePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as [String]
let storePath = String(storePaths[0]) as NSString
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

do {
  try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(storePath as String, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Error creating storePath \(storePath): \(error)")
}
let sqliteFilePath = storePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(storeName + ".sqlite")
return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: sqliteFilePath)
        }

         lazy var model : NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: self.modelURL)!

          var store : NSPersistentStore?

               lazy var coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.model)
do {
  self.store = try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(
    NSSQLiteStoreType,
    configuration: nil,
    URL: self.storeURL,
    options: self.options)
} catch var error as NSError {
  print("Store Error: \(error)")
  self.store = nil
} catch {
  fatalError()
}
return coordinator
     }()

             lazy var context : NSManagedObjectContext = {
let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
return context
       }()
    }
```

Comment: Don't update your question in the comments, update by selecting edit and adding additional detail at the end of the original question.

Comment: An `NSManagedObjectContext` does not require a persistent store to exist but it does need a persistent store to persist / save data. Perhaps you can provide more information in your question that details what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: I have detail my question ,he has save data ,

Comment: I readily need help,is you have any question about my description,i will check it immediately

Comment: The `CreateNoteViewController` doesn't initialise the `managedObjectContext`, but my guess is that it is initialised before the view controller is presented, for example in `prepareForSegue` in the preceding view controller.  This is a relatively common design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code snippet creates a managed object context:

```
lazy var context : NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
    return context
}()
```

Your second code snippet **does not create** a managed object context:

```
var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?
lazy var note: Note? = {
    if let context = self.managedObjectContext {
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? Note
    }
    return .None
}()
```

The second snippet is using Swift optional unwrapping to check that `self.managedObjectContext` is not nil. If it isn't nil, it assigns it to a local variable `context`. You don't set the persistent store coordinator here because you are not creating the managed object context. This code assumes that `self.managedObjectContext` was already created somewhere else (probably in the first snippet).

A managed object context isn't much use without a persistent store coordinator, and you can't do anything useful with it. You especially can't save data with it. But since your second code snippet isn't creating a managed object context, that doesn't matter here.

Comment: by the way ,you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible reasons why the coordinator is not a param to the init method.

Since a context can either work with a store coordinator or a parent context, init methods for each of these cases that also include the concurrency type param would be messy and make subclassing more tricky. So they instead opted to have a set once property, i.e. if you set them again it exceptions with an inconsistency "Context already has a coordinator;  cannot replace.".

Allowing a context to be created before it is ready to be used gives more flexibility to the initialisation routine of the app. First gives flexibility in how each part of the stack is created, model, coordinator, context, etc. And second, the context can be passed to view controllers first, and then the store loaded and coordinator set on the context afterwards. And the viewController can listen for `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` and then check if the context now has a valid coordinator and then perform its view updates.